# Visual Studio 2012 Resources Editor for non MFC applications

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc, visual-studio-2012

Visual Studio Resources Editor undoubtedly contains valuable set of tools that help when creating UI for MFC applications, especially various dialogue boxes and graphic elements.

I have reasons to stay with non-managed C++, which mean staying without the usage of Windows Forms. I therefore got an idea, **if it is possible to use resources created with VS2012 Resources Editor in non-managed C++** while creating non-MFC applications.

- How to refer to the GUI elements from within my non-managed C++ code?
- can I completely abandon MFC structure and use my own C++ design?
- Would you know about any good tutorial that covers this? I searched on the net and tried YouTube too, but I did not find suitable example covering this question.

*I use:*

- Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate
- Windows 7 x64
- non-managed C++

Thank you.

Comment: The resource editor doesn't have anything to do with MFC, it works for any Windows gui program.  Don't look for a tutorial, you need to read a book.  Start with Petzold's "Programming Windows".

Comment: @HansPassant: +1, hi and thanks for your response. If I understand correctly, the way .rc files are created is perfectly compatible with WinAPI, and I can apply standard WinAPI calls to display those UI components. I have already read Petzold, but I will open it again, to find answers on my question.

Answer (score 2):

MFC is essentially a wrapper around WinAPI and as such resource files can be used completely without MFC. At design/compile time:

1. Drag and drop your resources to create the `.rc` file
2. Include the generated header file - `#include "resource.h"`

At runtime:

1. In your code, make sure to call `InitCommonControlsEx`
2. Load the resources with WinAPI calls such as `DialogBox`, `CreateDialog`, etc.

Comment: +1, thank you for this positive answer. It is great to know, that I can create UIs quickly and visually without the need to rely on large .NET framework.